# Change of data in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having trouble understanding why **excel change containing data of a text file when opening it**.

Let's say I have a text file with changed extension "mydata.xls" which contains following lines:

```
01E0
01E1
```

and when I open it in excel it gives me following results:

```
1,00E+00
1,00E+01
```

Is there any way to avoid this?

**I would prefer vba solution to this issue.**

## Update 1

Bellow is snippet of a text file:

```
    Ordr    MaterialS   Description System Stat Version Tgt qty Bsc start   Basic fin.

9531422 1140413 NALSARTTING IECHO   RL  MSYT PCZF*  01E1        2.400   26.10.2015  01.11.2015
21531847 1201013    XALWARTTING IECHOO  RL  PCYF PRC  ASG  AAGS APRS BASC BCRQ* 01E1        25.500  26.10.2015  02.10.2015
    412714199   4443247826  FOKSAMAT    CETZ MSPT PEC  APG  APGS APRS BYRQ PUMN*    0101          4.250 02.11.2015  09.11.2015
```

Encoded in UCS-2 Little Endian.

Bellow is the vba code I'm using to open a file:

```
Workbooks.OpenText fileName:=path, Tab:=True, ThousandsSeparator:=".", DecimalSeparator:=","
Set openWb = ActiveWorkbook
```

Here is another example:

```
    0100 goes to 100
    0101 goes to 101
    0102 goes to 102
    0103 goes to 103
```

Comment: Why a `text file` is called `mydata.xls`? The extension `xls` means a Excel file in `BIFF` format. And "I do prefer vba solution to this issue." means what? You have Excel running and need opening the text file as a new workbook or need importing the text file's content in a existing worksheet?

Comment: Because I'm using SAP to export data to a local file and I didn't know that SAP only changes extension of a text file to xls. I have a excel workbook running, And I just need to open exported file to copy data to the existing workbook.

Comment: Then you should more explain the kind of text file since I suspect there is more than one field. So What kind of text file? Are the different fields tabulator delimited? Comma delimited? Semicolon delimited? Fixed width? Please post a at least 3 row example of the content in your question. Also what is the encoding? UFT-8? ANSI aka Windows 1252? Other?

Comment: Open the `mydata.xls` with a text editor to explore its content.

Comment: I just posted an update. Take a look guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I assumed the file is tabulator delimited and there are 8 columns and the 4. column is "System Status" with content 01E1.

[image]

I would suggest the following approach:

Let the VBA insert a new worksheet, then a QueryTable within that worksheet. With this we have more control over the column types. Then, after refresh the QueryTable, get the content from this worksheet and if done, delete that worksheet.

```
Sub Makro1()

 Dim oQueryTable As QueryTable

 Set oSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

 Set oQueryTable = oSheet.QueryTables _
        .Add(Connection:="TEXT;C:\Users\axel\Desktop\mydata.xls", _
        Destination:=oSheet.Cells(1, 1))

 With oQueryTable
        .Name = "mydata"
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlTextFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlDMYFormat, xlDMYFormat)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
 End With

  'from here on the code which gets the data from oSheet

 'oSheet.Delete

End Sub
```

Note the `.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlTextFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlDMYFormat, xlDMYFormat)` this describes the content type of each of the 8 columns. I set column 4 to text content. So it will not be interpreted as a number in exponential notation.

Result:

[image]